# Prevent certain commands from being logged by history in powershell

Tags: powershell

In bash, if you don't want some chore commands to be remembered by history, for instance `dir` or `cd..` or `h`, you can put them in `HISTIGNORE`. Is this possible in powershell?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible in powershell?

You can achieve the similar behavior by running the following command:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -HistorySaveStyle SaveNothing
```

If PSReadLine is installed you can install it with the following command:

```
Install-Module PSReadLine
```

If you are an Administrator on the system you can add the following command to your PowerShell profile to get nearly identical behavior. In the example I provided if the command starts with a space the command won’t be added to the history handler:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -AddToHistoryHandler {
    param($command)
    if ($command -like ' *') {
        return $false
    }
    return $true
}
```

Sources:

1. [Get-PSReadLineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/get-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7.3)
2. [Set-PSReadLineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7.3)
3. [How to Run a PowerShell Command without Saving it to History?](https://woshub.com/powershell-commands-history/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20get%20the%20current%20PowerShell%20history%20file,text%20file%2C%20run%20the%20command%3A%20Set-PSReadlineOption%20-HistorySaveStyle%20SaveNothing)

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, thanks. I saw you modified the answer to add a second section. Is the first section a non-answer and should be removed?